# Envio de Push chegando frenéticamente ou não chega

Tags: php, ios, apple-push-notification

Tenho um sistema que envia notificações pushs para os dispositivos que tem instalado um aplicativo. Especificamente no iOS está chegando várias vezes (30 e mais) o mesmo push.

No Android está acontecendo o seguinte erro:

```
https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send connection refused: port 443
```

Estou fazendo assim no iOS:

```
private function sendIosPush($title, $message, $token, $data = null){

    /* Define Gateway de Conexão */
    $production = true;

    if ($production){
        $gateway = 'ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195';
    }
    else {
        $gateway = 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195';
    }

    $ctx = stream_context_create();

    // Is Your Certificate File
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', '/certs/ck.pem');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', 'senha');
    stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'cafile', '/certs/entrust_2048_ca.cer');

    // Open a Connection to the APNS Server
    $fp = stream_socket_client(
        $gateway, $err,
        $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);

    if (!$fp)
        exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . PHP_EOL);

    // Create The Payload Body
    $body = [];
    $body['aps'] = array(
        'alert' => array(
            'title' => $title,
            'body' => $message,
         ),
        'sound' => 'default'
    );

    if(is_array($data)) $body += $data;

    // Encode the Payload as JSON
    $payload = json_encode($body);

    // Build the Binary Notification
    $msg = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $token) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;

    // Send it to the Server
    $result = fwrite($fp, $msg, strlen($msg));

    // Close the Connection to the Server
    fclose($fp);

    if (!$result)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}
```

Quando o push é enviado eu coloco um flag na linha da tabela dizendo que ele já foi e por isso não precisa enviar novamente. Essa lógica está funcionando. Testei fazendo a consulta no banco de dados antes de enviar um push manualmente e depois. O registro não consta mais na consulta.

Estou achando que pode ser um parâmetro que não estou enviando ou algo do tipo.

E no Android estou fazendo assim:

```
$fields = array(
    'registration_ids'  => $registerIds, // registers ids
    'data'              => $msg
);

$headers = array(
    'Authorization: key='.$this->android_push_key, // GCM KEY
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result         = curl_exec($ch);
$header_size    = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
$httpcode       = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
$body           = substr($result, $header_size);

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Veja se dá uma luz :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12919156/apple-push-notification-service-sends-repeated-notifications#answer-13361561

Comment: Legal @MagicHat. Deu uma luz realmente. Agora, como será que eu descubro a porta que esse sistema usa? Eu estou usando o APNS mesmo.

Comment: Ou ainda :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12866600/duplicate-apple-apns-push-notifications#answer-12891443

Comment: Eu sei de uma coisa, no retorno do APNS sempre retorna 1443, naquele $result no final do código.